# How to chain Optional#ifPresent() in lambda without nesting?

Tags: java, lambda, option-type

I have the following code block that requires that I check whether multiple nested variables are present. These were originally null checks that I replaced with `Optional` and `ifPresent()`.

I would like to use `ifPresent()` instead of querying `get()` to mitigate potential runtime exceptions. But this is causing a lot of nesting.

Can I leverage lambdas in this example to achieve the same flow without the nesting?

```
void SomeMethod() {
    procA().ifPresent(a -> {
       procB(a).ifPresent(b -> {
          // Do something

          return;
       });
    });

    throw new SomeException();
}
```

Comment: What's the point of the return statement?

Comment: To avoid dropping down into the exception.

Comment: You can't return from the outer method inside a lambda. Anyway, if you want to throw a custom exception, you should use `orElseThrow()`.

Comment: I've updated my code. I can't return as I wrote it?

Comment: No. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-):

```
procA().flatMap(this::procB).ifPresent(b -> {
    // do something
});
```

As for the return statement, you can't return from the outer method inside the lambda. If you want to throw a custom exception when the value is missing, use [`orElseThrow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow-java.util.function.Supplier-):

```
B b = procA()
        .flatMap(this::procB)
        .orElseThrow(SomeException::new);

// do something with b
```

Or, of course you could just call [`get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#get--) and let it throw a `NoSuchElementException`.

Comment: Hello. Would you mind improving your answer where the inner-scope has both `a` and `b` available? Your `flatMap` example has only `b`.

Comment: Hmm... I can't think of an elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps (or am i missing what you don't like about gets?)

```
static Optional<String> getA() {
    return Optional.of("a");
}

static Optional<String> getB(String b) {
    return Optional.of(b + "!");
}

static void test() {
    Optional<String> a, b;
    a = getA();
    if (a.isPresent() && (b = getB(a.get())).isPresent()) {
        System.out.println(b.get());
    }
}
```

Comment: Optional#get() is unsafe and not better then the "usual" null check. (See: http://dzone.com/articles/java-8-optional-replace-your-get-calls)

Comment: get is safe after isPresent.

Comment: It's only safe if one remembers to call `ifPresent()` on it beforehand and there isn't a logic error at that point or sometime in the future when/if code is refactored. It is safer to avoid it entirely.