# How to chain lambdas with all optional values available at the innermost scope without nesting Optional#ifPresent()?

Tags: java, lambda, option-type

This is an offshoot of my other question: [How to chain Optional#ifPresent() in lambda without nesting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46802131)

However, the problem now is how to provide a lambda solution where all of the optional values are available at the innermost scope:

```
B b = procA().flatMap(this::procB).orElseThrow(SomeException::new);

// Value from procA() is not available.
```

My original code was:

```
void SomeMethod() {
    procA().ifPresent(a -> {
       procB(a).ifPresent(b -> {
          // Do something with a and b

          return;
       });
    });

    throw new SomeException();
}
```

I understand that the `return` at the innermost scope is wrong. The new `flatMap` example illustrates the correct behavior.

I am using `ifPresent()` instead of `get()` to avoid potential runtime exceptions where I might fail to check whether the value of an optional `isPresent()`.

Comment: They are available. You can do something with a and b. What is the problem?

Comment: `a` is not available using the `flatMap` method. I want to avoid nesting `ifPresent()` in such a way that both `a` and `b` are available at the innermost scope and an exception can be thrown if any of the nesting fails.

Answer (score 1):

I find this question very interesting as chained calls with potential `null` returns are a common nuisance, and Optional can shorten the usual null check chain a lot. But the issue there is that the nature of the functional stream methods hides the intermediate values in the mapping functions. Nesting is a way to keep them available, but can also get annoying if the length of the call chain grows, as you have realized.

I cannot think of an easy and lightweight solution, but if the nature of your project leads to these situations regularly, this util class could help:

```
public static class ChainedOptional<T>
{
    private final List<Object> intermediates;

    private final Optional<T>  delegate;

    private ChainedOptional(List<Object> previousValues, Optional<T> delegate)
    {
        this.intermediates = new ArrayList<>(previousValues);
        intermediates.add(delegate.orElse(null));
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    public static <T> ChainedOptional<T> of(T value)
    {
        return of(Optional.ofNullable(value));
    }

    public static <T> ChainedOptional<T> of(Optional<T> delegate)
    {
        return new ChainedOptional<>(new ArrayList<>(), delegate);
    }

    public <R> ChainedOptional<R> map(Function<T, R> mapper)
    {
        return new ChainedOptional<>(intermediates, delegate.map(mapper));
    }

    public ChainedOptional<T> ifPresent(Consumer<T> consumer)
    {
        delegate.ifPresent(consumer);
        return this;
    }

    public ChainedOptional<T> ifPresent(BiConsumer<List<Object>, T> consumer)
    {
        delegate.ifPresent(value -> consumer.accept(intermediates, value));
        return this;
    }

    public <X extends Throwable> T orElseThrow(Supplier<? extends X> exceptionSupplier)
        throws X
    {
        return delegate.orElseThrow(exceptionSupplier);
    }

    public <X extends Throwable> T orElseThrow(Function<List<Object>, X> exceptionSupplier)
        throws X
    {
        return orElseThrow(() -> exceptionSupplier.apply(intermediates));
    }
}
```

You use it by wrapping an Optional or a plain value. When you then use the `map` method to chain method calls, it will provide a new ChainedOptional while storing the current value in a list. At the end (`ifPresent`, `orElseThrow`), you will not only get the last value, but also the list of all intermediate values. Since it is not known how many calls will be chained, I did not find a way to store those values in a type-safe way, though.

See examples here:

```
ChainedOptional.of(1)
               .map(s -> s + 1)
               .map(s -> "hello world")
               .map(s -> (String) null)
               .map(String::length)
               .ifPresent((intermediates, result) -> {
                   System.out.println(intermediates);
                   System.out.println("Result: " + result);
               })
               .orElseThrow(intermediates -> {
                   System.err.println(intermediates);
                   return new NoSuchElementException();
               });

// [1, 2, hello world, null, null]
// Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
//    at ... 

ChainedOptional.of(1)
               .map(s -> s + 1)
               .map(s -> "hello world")
               // .map(s -> (String) null)
               .map(String::length)
               .ifPresent((intermediates, result) -> {
                   System.out.println(intermediates);
                   System.out.println("Result: " + result);
               })
               .orElseThrow(intermediates -> {
                   System.err.println(intermediates);
                   return new NoSuchElementException();
               });

// [1, 2, hello world, 11]
// Result: 11
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if you come up with a nicer solution.

Comment: This was very inspiring and I made some improvements and made it a bit more complete (for Java 8 right now). It can be found at: https://github.com/castortech/ChainedOptional