# How to throw an exception where nested lambdas fail to reach the innermost scope?

Tags: java, lambda

I want to nest some lambdas as such where an exception is thrown if the innermost scope is not reached. How can this be done?

```
boolean someError = true;

procA(new Object()).ifPresent(a -> {
   procB(a).ifPresent(b -> {
      System.out.println(a);
      System.out.println(b);

      // Can't do this: "Local variable someError in an enclosing scope must
      // be final or effectively final"
      someError = false;
   });
});

if (someError)
   throw new RuntimeException("Some error!");
```

This is similar to my other question: [How to chain lambdas with all optional values available at the innermost scope without nesting Optional#ifPresent()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46802484)

The difference is that nesting `ifPresent()` is allowed. Using `get()` is still not allowed for the purpose of avoiding potential runtime exceptions on a failure to check whether the value of an optional isPresent().

Answer (score 0):

I thoroughly believe that you're using the wrong approach for what you're trying to do. generally it's debated whether methods in java should return Optionals. I believe they should only in cases of a project where null is entirely avoided.

without knowing what exactly happens in procA and procB, it's very hard to reason about refactoring this to be better. My guess is that encapsulation and abstraction between procA and procB are not ideal.

Here is what might make it work without bigger refactorings:

```
Optional<ReturnOfProcB> result = procA(paramA).map(this::procB);
if(!result.isPresent()) {
    throw new IllegalStateException(); 
}
```