# Calling different methods based on values of two Optionals

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

While working with Java 8 Optionals I face following scenario very frequently. I have two `Optional` objects and then I want to call different methods based on the values (`ifPresent`) of those Optionals.

Here is an example:

```
void example(Optional<String> o1, Optional<String> o2) throws Exception {
    if (o1.isPresent() && o2.isPresent()) {
       handler1(o1.get(), o2.get());
    } else if (o1.isPresent()) {
       handler2(o1.get());
    } else if (o2.isPresent()) {
       handler3(o2.get());
    } else {
       throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

However, this chain of `if-else` statements doesn't seem like a proper way of working with `Optional` (after all, they were added so that you can avoid writing these `if-else` checks everywhere in your code).

What is the proper way of doing this with `Optional` objects?

Comment: Optionals were not added to avoid if-else checks. They were added to make it clear that a method can return nothing instead of what it usually returns, in a way that forces the caller to handle the nothing case. If you use them to avoid if/else checks, you're abusing them.

Comment: Have you seen: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46802484/how-to-chain-lambdas-with-all-optional-values-available-at-the-innermost-scope-w>?

Comment: A slightly more compact version could be:
    `void example(Optional<String> o1, Optional<String> o2) throws Exception {
        o1.ifPresent(val1 -> o2.ifPresent(val2 -> handler1(val1, val2)));
        o1.ifPresent(val1 -> { if (!o2.isPresent()) handler2(val1); });
        o2.ifPresent(val2 -> { if (!o1.isPresent()) handler3(val2); });
        if (!o1.isPresent() && !o2.isPresent()) throw new Exception();
    }`

With this you get automatic unwrapping of the values (no need for `get`). Still ugly, though. You could get rid of the final line, if throwing an exception is not necessary.

Answer (score 6):

You said that you use such structure frequently, so I propose to introduce a Helper `class`:

```
final class BiOptionalHelper<F, S> {
    private final Optional<F> first;
    private final Optional<S> second;

    public BiOptionalHelper(Optional<F> first, Optional<S> second){
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    public BiOptionalHelper<F, S> ifFirstPresent(Consumer<? super F> ifPresent){
        if (!second.isPresent()) {
            first.ifPresent(ifPresent);
        }
        return this;
    }

    public BiOptionalHelper<F, S> ifSecondPresent(Consumer<? super S> ifPresent){
        if (!first.isPresent()) {
            second.ifPresent(ifPresent);
        }
        return this;
    }

    public BiOptionalHelper<F, S> ifBothPresent(BiConsumer<? super F, ? super S> ifPresent){
        if(first.isPresent() && second.isPresent()){
            ifPresent.accept(first.get(), second.get());
        }
        return this;
    }

    public <T extends Throwable> void orElseThrow(Supplier<? extends T> exProvider) throws T{
        if(!first.isPresent() && !second.isPresent()){
            throw exProvider.get();
        }
    }
}
```

Which then may be used in a way like this:

```
new BiOptionalHelper<>(o1, o2)
    .ifBothPresent(this::handler1)
    .ifFirstPresent(this::handler2)
    .ifSecondPresent(this::handler3)
    .orElseThrow(Exception::new);
```

Though, this just moves your problem into a separate `class`.

**Note**: above code may be refactored to not use `Optional` and `isPresent()` checks at all. And just use `null` for `first` and `second` and replace `isPresent()` with `null`-checks.

As it is generally a bad design to store `Optional` in fields or accept them as parameters in the first place. As JB Nizet already pointed out in a comment to the question.

---

Another way it to move that logic into common helper method:

```
public static <F, S, T extends Throwable> void handle(Optional<F> first, Optional<S> second, 
                                                      BiConsumer<F, S> bothPresent, Consumer<F> firstPresent, 
                                                      Consumer<S> secondPresent, Supplier<T> provider) throws T{
    if(first.isPresent() && second.isPresent()){
        bothPresent.accept(first.get(), second.get());
    } else if(first.isPresent()){
        firstPresent.accept(first.get());
    } else if(second.isPresent()){
        secondPresent.accept(second.get());
    } else{
        throw provider.get();
    }
}
```

Which then could be called like this:

```
handle(o1, o2, this::handler1, this::handler2, this::handler3, Exception::new);
```

But it's still kind of messy to be honest.

Comment: This `BiOptionalHelper` is really nice! The `handle` method, on the other hand, is really bad and unintuitive, like you admitted yourself ;) One note: I'd replace `first.ifPresent(s1 -> second.ifPresent(s2 -> ifPresent.accept(s1, s2)));` with much clearer `if (first.isPresent() && second.isPresent()) { ifPresent.accept(first.get(), second.get(); }` (it'd even match the body of `orElseThrow` then).

Comment: Doesn't the `BiOptionalHelper` end up invoking both `handler1`, `handler2`, as well as `handler3`, when both values are present, or am I missing something? OP only wants to invoke `handler2` or `handler3` when only one value is present.

Comment: @JanusVarmarken completly right, I didn't notice that one, will need to come up with something different. One would probably need to instead of `return` this, return something that has already been executed

Comment: @TomaszLinkowski not really... as it does not do what the OP wants, read previous comments

Comment: @Lino but in that case you would not be able to chain those methods

Comment: @Lino I think you can fix it by inserting the `if` checks I use in the comment I made to the question text in your `ifFirstPresent` and `ifSecondPresent`.

Comment: @Eugene maybe use an internal *executed* flag with a second private constructor, which initially is set to `false`

Comment: I'll fiddle around a bit more and try to come up with a better solution

Comment: @Lino it would have to be an array of a single boolean btw, since you would need to update it from within a lambda expression

Comment: Suggested an edit that I believe solves it, but it essentially just moves what the OP is doing in his current code to your helper class

Comment: @JanusVarmarken well, may be that would be acceptable by the OP, I actually don't like all this overhead that is being done here, and would go for the helper method, for which +1 (with the additional fixes suggested)

Comment: @Lino You lost me, sorry. I just suggested to wrap the invocations of `ifPresent` `Consumer`s in an if-check, e.g., `public BiOptionalHelper<F, S> ifFirstPresent(Consumer<? super F> ifPresent){
        if (!second.isPresent()) {
            first.ifPresent(ifPresent);
        }
        return this;
    }` I don't believe there's a need for keeping track of state if you do this.

Comment: @Lino Thanks for taking effort of writing this class. It is certainly helpful. I can not use it in my current codebase. But I think it is a good addition if you are working with `Optional`s a lot!

Comment: @Nullpointer You are welcome, and that's sad to hear that. As you may have seen and read across all the other answers and comments: it is probably the best, to just stick with the code you currently have, or use the helper method in the second part of my answer

Comment: @Eugene @Lino Please, do not suggest using this helper method to people. Would you guys like to work with code that uses it? ;) I mean, it's totally unintuitive when you see it used, especially when both `Optional`s are of the same type. Until Java has [named parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_parameter), I believe such methods should be avoided. As to the overhead related to using the helper class, it's entirely optimized out by the JIT and its [escape analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_analysis#Optimizations) (meaning the object is not even allocated on the heap).

Comment: @TomaszLinkowski that object not being allocated on the heap is called scalarization. And I actually like that method and yes I used use it. I've looked at your code and it expresses the intention a lot better, agreed, but the amount of code...

Comment: @Eugene Well, I generally like your code here on SO, but this method - it's scary :P As to amount of code in `BiOptionalHelper`: it's not business logic, it's utility code, like `ReferencePipeline` implementing `Stream`. So their internals do not have to be that readable until their contracts are clear & intuitive. So I'd say that: 1) the original OP's code is quite clear (if a little verbose), 2) `BiOptionalHelper` usage may look a bit strange at first, but at least it's clear about what it does, 3) the **6**-parameter helper method, though - this can *really* obscure the business logic.

Comment: @TomaszLinkowski comment coming on your answer soon... plz give me some time

Answer (score 6):

*Disclaimer:* My answer is based on [Lino's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51848700/2032415) - the first part of this answer (`BiOptional<T, U>`) is a modified version of [Lino's `BiOptionalHelper`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51848700/2032415), while the second part (`BiOptionalMapper<T, U, R>`) is my idea for extending this nice pattern.

I like [Lino's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51848700/2032415) a lot. However, I feel that instead of calling it `BiOptionalHelper`, it deserves to be simply called `BiOptional`, provided that:

- it gets `Optional<T> first()` and `Optional<T> second()` methods
- it gets `is(First/Second)Present`, `is(First/Second)OnlyPresent` and `are(Both/None)Present` methods
- `if(First/Second)Present` methods are renamed to `if(First/Second)OnlyPresent`
- it gets `ifNonePresent(Runnable action)` method
- `orElseThrow` method is renamed to `ifNonePresentThrow`

Finally (and this is the entirely original part of my answer), I realized this pattern could support not only "handling" (in `BiOptional`), but also "mapping" (in `BiOptionalMapper` obtained through `BiOptional.mapper()`), like that:

```
BiOptional<String, Integer> biOptional = BiOptional.from(o1, o2);

// handler version
biOptional
        .ifBothPresent(this::handleBoth)
        .ifFirstOnlyPresent(this::handleFirst)
        .ifSecondOnlyPresent(this::handleSecond)
        .ifNonePresent(this::performAction);

// mapper version
String result = biOptional.<String>mapper()
        .onBothPresent(this::mapBoth)
        .onFirstOnlyPresent(this::mapFirst)
        .onSecondOnlyPresent(this::mapSecond)
        .onNonePresent("default")
        .result();

Optional<String> optionalResult = biOptional.<String>mapper()
        .onBothPresent(this::mapBoth)
        .onNonePresentThrow(IllegalStateException::new)
        .optionalResult();
```

Note that one can either:

- call all `on*Present` mapping methods, and then call `R result()` (which will throw if `result` were to be absent), or
- call only some of them, and then call `Optional<R> optionalResult()`

Note also that:

- in order to avoid confusion between "handling" and "mapping", the naming convention is as follows:

  - `BiOptional`: `if*Present`
  - `BiOptionalMapper`: `on*Present`
- if any of the `on*Present` methods is called twice, `BiOptionalMapper` will throw if `result` were to be overwritten (unlike `BiOptional`, which can handle multiple `if*Present` calls)
- `result` cannot be *set* to `null` by the mappers provided to `on*Present` or by calling `onNonePresent(R)` (`Optional<...>` should be used as result type `R` instead)

Here's the source code of the two classes:

```
final class BiOptional<T, U> {

    @Nullable
    private final T first;
    @Nullable
    private final U second;

    public BiOptional(T first, U second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    public static <T, U> BiOptional<T, U> from(Optional<T> first, Optional<U> second) {
        return new BiOptional<>(first.orElse(null), second.orElse(null));
    }

    public Optional<T> first() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(first);
    }

    public Optional<U> second() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(second);
    }

    public boolean isFirstPresent() {
        return first != null;
    }

    public boolean isSecondPresent() {
        return second != null;
    }

    public boolean isFirstOnlyPresent() {
        return isFirstPresent() && !isSecondPresent();
    }

    public boolean isSecondOnlyPresent() {
        return !isFirstPresent() && isSecondPresent();
    }

    public boolean areBothPresent() {
        return isFirstPresent() && isSecondPresent();
    }

    public boolean areNonePresent() {
        return !isFirstPresent() && !isSecondPresent();
    }

    public BiOptional<T, U> ifFirstOnlyPresent(Consumer<? super T> ifFirstOnlyPresent) {
        if (isFirstOnlyPresent()) {
            ifFirstOnlyPresent.accept(first);
        }
        return this;
    }

    public BiOptional<T, U> ifSecondOnlyPresent(Consumer<? super U> ifSecondOnlyPresent) {
        if (isSecondOnlyPresent()) {
            ifSecondOnlyPresent.accept(second);
        }
        return this;
    }

    public BiOptional<T, U> ifBothPresent(BiConsumer<? super T, ? super U> ifBothPresent) {
        if (areBothPresent()) {
            ifBothPresent.accept(first, second);
        }
        return this;
    }

    public BiOptional<T, U> ifNonePresent(Runnable ifNonePresent) {
        if (areNonePresent()) {
            ifNonePresent.run();
        }
        return this;
    }

    public <X extends Throwable> void ifNonePresentThrow(Supplier<? extends X> throwableProvider) throws X {
        if (areNonePresent()) {
            throw throwableProvider.get();
        }
    }

    public <R> BiOptionalMapper<T, U, R> mapper() {
        return new BiOptionalMapper<>(this);
    }
}
```

and:

```
final class BiOptionalMapper<T, U, R> {

    private final BiOptional<T, U> biOptional;
    private R result = null;

    BiOptionalMapper(BiOptional<T, U> biOptional) {
        this.biOptional = biOptional;
    }

    public BiOptionalMapper<T, U, R> onFirstOnlyPresent(Function<? super T, ? extends R> firstMapper) {
        if (biOptional.isFirstOnlyPresent()) {
            setResult(firstMapper.apply(biOptional.first().get()));
        }
        return this;
    }

    public BiOptionalMapper<T, U, R> onSecondOnlyPresent(Function<? super U, ? extends R> secondMapper) {
        if (biOptional.isSecondOnlyPresent()) {
            setResult(secondMapper.apply(biOptional.second().get()));
        }
        return this;
    }

    public BiOptionalMapper<T, U, R> onBothPresent(BiFunction<? super T, ? super U, ? extends R> bothMapper) {
        if (biOptional.areBothPresent()) {
            setResult(bothMapper.apply(biOptional.first().get(), biOptional.second().get()));
        }
        return this;
    }

    public BiOptionalMapper<T, U, R> onNonePresent(Supplier<? extends R> supplier) {
        if (biOptional.areNonePresent()) {
            setResult(supplier.get());
        }
        return this;
    }

    public BiOptionalMapper<T, U, R> onNonePresent(R other) {
        if (biOptional.areNonePresent()) {
            setResult(other);
        }
        return this;
    }

    public <X extends Throwable> BiOptionalMapper<T, U, R> onNonePresentThrow(Supplier<? extends X> throwableProvider) throws X {
        biOptional.ifNonePresentThrow(throwableProvider);
        return this;
    }

    public R result() {
        if (result == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Result absent");
        }
        return result;
    }

    public Optional<R> optionalResult() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(result);
    }

    private void setResult(R result) {
        if (result == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Null obtained from a mapper");
        }
        if (this.result != null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Result already present: " + this.result);
        }
        this.result = result;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1+ for the effort in this one, it clearly denotes the intention, a few things I don't like : `isFirstPresent` and the like are implementation details, I would make them private; I would remove `first/second` methods entirely (since this is not what this utility is for IMO); I would leave `areBothPresent` only and simply do `!areBothPresent()` when needed. More coming after the short review we will have internally on this, apparently my team lead loves it and says move it to the `xxx.HolgerUtil` package :) so... I guess I'm wrong, which is the main reason I'm here to begin with(read "NICE!")

Comment: I agree with @Eugene, `BiOptional` is not used to store the `Optional`s, but just to handle them, which leaves all those helper methods unused and useless.

Comment: Also I made once a true `BiOptional`, you can see it here: https://ideone.com/LoIgCa. Which might be interesting for your `xxx.HolgerUtil` @Eugene ;)

Comment: @Lino indeed... I had already ideas to code such a thing, and you both bring great inspiration into the picture, thank you!

Comment: @Eugene You're welcome, as a note: the `BiOptional` from me just executes when *both* values are present, and will do nothing when it's `empty`. So it behaves differently than the one provided in this answer

Comment: @Eugene Well, I *meant* `BiOptional` to correspond to `Optional` and - only as one of its features - to solve the OP's problem. Now I see, however, that it'd have problematic consequences, namely it's frowned upon to use `Optional` in non-return context, and here I use `BiOptional` in such a way. So I agree about those extra methods. As to `areNonePresent` in general: note that  `Optional` will finally get an [`isEmpty`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#isEmpty()) method in Java 11. All in all, I'm glad you liked it, thank you :)

Comment: @Lino Your `BiOptional` is interesting, although I'm not sure I have ever encountered a use case for it :) But in retrospect, both your and my `BiOptional` have the main drawback of being too general (like tuples), so after all, I think I agree more with your treating this class in this Q&A more as a helper class than a full `BiOptional`. It just doesn't encourage uses other than "handling" and "mapping", like using `BiOptional` as a return type, which brings us too close too tuples (which Java [rather won't have](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2010-March/003995.html)).

Comment: @TomaszLinkowski you say finally will get `isEmpty` meaning you like that? Sorry, I really didn't understand that addition. Well, could be used as a method reference Predicate I guess `.filter(Optional::isEmpty)` but same thing could be done via `.filter(x -> !x.isPresent())` or in java-11 `Predicate.not(Optional::isPresent)`... any other reasons I might be missing that you know about?

Comment: @Eugene Yes, I like `Optional.isEmpty` because I like clarity. I prefer `if (optional.isEmpty())` over `if (!optional.isPresent())`, and I *much* prefer `.anyMatch(Optional::isEmpty)` than `.anyMatch(x -> !x.isPresent())` or even `.anyMatch(Predicate.not(Optional::isPresent))`. Other examples of such duality: `Objects.isNull/isNonNull`, `Stream.anyMatch/noneMatch`, JUnit's `Assert.assertFalse/True`, [`StringUtils.isEmpty/isNotEmpty`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/), jOOλ's [`Seq.isEmpty/isNotEmpty`](https://www.jooq.org/products/jOOλ/javadoc/0.9.14/org/jooq/lambda/Seq.html).

Comment: @TomaszLinkowski in *such* a case let's propose `Collections`: `isEmpty` and `isNotEmpty` and the same for every single `Map` and for `String` and for every single utility does around `String`.. I bet I can find lot's of other cases too. This is not something we will agree on, but we don't have to, each person has it's take. We prohibit this in our code, well *our* is the keyword here. thx for your time, should I start looking into adding `jOOλ` to our project? hmmm

Comment: @Eugene Let's continue in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178118/room-for-tomasz-linkowski-and-eugene).

Answer (score 3):

To avoid `if` statements or here `if (Optional.isPresent())` you should have a common way  to handle the `Optional` values but it is not the case as according their content you may invoke a function with the functional interface `Consumer<String>` or `BiConsumer<String, String>`.

As hint, you may factor the second part  but it is not more readable or a better way :

```
if (o1.isPresent() && o2.isPresent()) {
    handler1(o1.get(), o2.get());
} else {
    Map<Optional<String>, Consumer<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(o1, this::handler2);
    map.put(o2, this::handler3);
    Optional<String> opt = Stream.of(o1, o2)
                                 .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                                 .findFirst()
                                 .orElseThrow(Exception::new);

    map.get(opt)
       .accept(opt.get());
}
```

If  you have much more `Optional`s to handle in this way  such as  this would probably make more sense but still it is a lot of code to write.

---

A more readable alternative could be to introduce a `Rule` class that stores the information required to trigger that if required :

```
public Rule(BiPredicate<Optional<String>, Optional<String>> ruleFunction, Runnable runnableIfApplied) {
    this.ruleFunction = ruleFunction;
    this.runnable = runnableIfApplied;
}
```

The `BiPredicate<Optional<String>, Optional<String>>` represents the matching function and the `Runnable` is the method to execute if the matching occurs.
You could move the rule execution logic in a `Rule` `static` method.
The idea is to make as clear as possible the rule specifications from the client side such as :

```
void example(Optional<String> o1, Optional<String> o2, Optional<String> o3) throws Exception {

    Rule.executeFirstMatchOrFail(o1, o2, 
                                   new Rule((opt1, opt2) -> opt1.isPresent() && opt2.isPresent(), () -> handler1(o1.get(), o2.get())),
                                   new Rule((opt1, opt2) -> opt1.isPresent(), () -> handler2(o1.get())), 
                                   new Rule((opt1, opt2) -> opt2.isPresent(), () -> handler3(o2.get())));
}
```

`Rule` could look like :

```
public class Rule {

    static void executeFirstMatchOrFail(Optional<String> o1, Optional<String> o2, Rule... rules) throws Exception {
        for (Rule rule : rules) {
            if (rule.apply(o1, o2)) {
                return;
            }
        }
        throw new Exception();
    }

    private Runnable runnable;
    private BiPredicate<Optional<String>, Optional<String>> ruleFunction;

    public Rule(BiPredicate<Optional<String>, Optional<String>> ruleFunction, Runnable runnableIfApplied) {
        this.ruleFunction = ruleFunction;
        this.runnable = runnableIfApplied;
    }

    public boolean apply(Optional<String> o1, Optional<String> o2) {
        if (ruleFunction.test(o1,o2)) {
            runnable.run();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. This does help but as you said it is much more applicable in cases where you have multiple Optionals. I guess I will have to stick with simple `if-else` in this case to maintain readability of code (unless there is some other advantage of using your approach?).

Comment: @davidxxx well, it took me 5 minutes to understand the code vs 10 seconds for the `if/else`... that is above abusing I guess

Comment: @Eugene With the actual code of the OP it complicates more things . I agree totally.

Comment: @Nullpointer You are welcome. There is really not ad advantage to use the code I write. This just a code that shows how avoid the conditional statements but it is more complex. So it also shows that for your case it is not relevant and the `if`s appear better.

Comment: Good addition, I like the concept of that rule. I would suggest to replace `BiFunction<Optional<String>, Optional<String>, Boolean>` with `BiPredicate<Optional<String>, Optional<String>` though

Comment: Hi Lino. Arg... I don't use often it. Thanks for this nice remark. I updated.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn’t really answer your question, but since Java 9 I would prefer something along these lines:

```
    o1.ifPresentOrElse(s1 -> {
        o2.ifPresentOrElse(s2 -> {
               handler1(s1, s2);
        }, () -> {
               handler2(s1);
        });
    }, () -> {
        o2.ifPresentOrElse(s2 -> {
               handler3(s2);
        }, () -> {
               throw new IllegalArgumentException("Neither was present");
        });
    });
```

There’s a rule of thumb about `Optional` saying not to use `isPresent` and `get`. I do use them very occasionally; most often they are better avoided.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting this approach, but I think using simple `if-else` conditions is much readable as compared to this?

Comment: note that throwing a checked `Exception` will not work

Comment: @OleV.V. as a side note there was a proposal to deprecate `get` entirely, thus java-10 has the addition of `orElseThrow()`...

Comment: Correct, @Lino, that would have to be an unchecked exception, or the last `ifPresentOrElse` should be replaced by an application of `orElseThrow`.